# Karate UI testing

Tags: karate

I was trying to do a POC with the karate test framework for UI application.
We are using Chrome browser.We are required to test the application incognito mode( Or we need to clear the cache and history every-time to get the test running)
what should be the driver type options that we should use to run application in incognito Mode.

Comment: What application you are using for your tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about that because Karate will start each Chrome instance in a new `--user-data-dir`. If you really want you can customize it (refer docs).

And `--incognito` passed as a command-line option will do what you want. Look for the `addOptions` in the driver settings.

Comment: Thank you Peter.New Chrome instance itself is addressing our issue now.

Comment: Thank you Peter.I am a new user and thank you for the guidance

Comment: @ArunThomas Is it working for u can u give the sample code for launching chrome in incognito mode